# Here Maps unable to import CustomizableScheme

Tags: android, heremaps

I am unable to add CustomizableScheme using here maps sdk. I have placed hereSDK.arr in raw folder

import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.customization.CustomizableScheme; is un available

I would like to change the theme to DARKMODE
CustomizableScheme scheme = map.createCustomizableScheme("newCustomScheme", Map.Scheme.NORMAL_DAY);

Answer (score 1):

**There is a method to set mapscheme using mapview**

```
  mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapScheme.NORMAL_NIGHT, mapError -> {
        if (mapError == null) {
            if (displayLocation() != null) {
                defaultCoordinates = new GeoCoordinates(displayLocation().getLatitude(), displayLocation().getLongitude());
            }
            mapView.getCamera().lookAt(defaultCoordinates, mapMeasureZoom);
            mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView:" + mapError);
        }
    });
```